# Pandas Index example with repeated entries using hypothesis

Tags: python, pandas, python-hypothesis

I want to generate a `pandas.Index` with repeated entries, like this.

```
>>> pd.Index(np.random.choice(range(5), 10))
Int64Index([3, 0, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 0], dtype='int64')
```

So I wrote the following strategy:

```
from hypothesis.extra.pandas import indexes
from hypothesis.strategies import sampled_from

st_idx = indexes(
    elements=sampled_from(range(5)),
    min_size=10,
    max_size=10
)
```

However when I try to draw from a strategy like this, I get the following error:

```
>>> st_idx.example()
[...]
Unsatisfiable: Unable to satisfy assumptions of condition.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[...]
NoExamples: Could not find any valid examples in 100 tries
```

On some experimentation, I realised it only works if `min_size` is less than equal to the number of choices (<= 5 in this case).  However that means I'll never get repeated examples!

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: Apparently only the `indexes` strategy has `unique` set to `True` by default, setting it to `False` as mentioned in the answer below also works with my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the resulting index does not have to have any particular distribution then one way to get what you need is to use `integers` strategy and use `unique` parameter of `indexes` strategy to produce duplicates if needed:

```
import hypothesis.strategies as st

st_idx = indexes(
    st.integers(min_value=0, max_value=5), 
    min_size=10, max_size=10, 
    unique=False
)

st_idx.example()
```

Producing:

```
Int64Index([4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 0, 5, 0, 0], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: huh! I think I completely misread the default argument for `unique`.  My approach also works with `unique=False`.  I guess I got confused because for all other strategies `unique` defaults to `False`.